# Voltage only appears when there connected to a load

Tags: voltage

The back story to the situation is a Dyson handheld vacuum cleaner which is powered by a 24V D.C battery. The cleaner has a separate D.C motor which powers a rotating brush, in addition to the one in the unit that develops the suction.

The spade connectors which connect to the motor which power the rotating brush read 0 Volts when not connected, but when connected to the motor read 16V D.C.

Why is it that when it's not connected to the load it shows nothing between the spade connectors, but when it's connected it does show voltage?

Comment: "The terminals at the motor .... when connected to the motor " You might want to rewrite that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it that when it's not connected to the load it shows nothing between the spade connectors, but when it's connected it does show voltage?

The short answer is: Because that is how they designed it :-) There must be a reason for this design, even if we don't know it. However I have a hypothesis below.

Actually when I borrowed one of these handheld vacuum cleaners, my experiments showed a slightly different behaviour from your description.

When the main "trigger" switch was operated, power *was* applied to the terminals for the rotating brush head for approx. 2 seconds. If the rotating brush head isn't attached *or* if the rotating brush head is stalled (i.e. cannot move), *then* power is removed from that motor's terminals.

My hypothesis at the time, was that there is likely some kind of monitoring for the rotating brush head motor's current, and a "window comparator". The design could be: If that motor's current drain is excessively high or low (i.e. outside of the expected "window" or range of current values) then power is removed from the motor after 2 seconds.

You stated that voltage was not applied to the rotating brush motor terminals, when there was no motor attached. Either the model I tested had a different behaviour (since power *was* applied to the terminals for the rotating brush, for 2 seconds in my tests), or you measured it more than 2 seconds after the main motor was started, and the power had already been applied *and then removed* from the rotating brush motor's terminals.

Removing power from a stalled motor seems like a good thing to do, and removing power from a potentially abnormal motor (where the current is too low) also seems a valid decision - and having no motor attached falls into the latter category too, with no interest to anyone who doesn't investigate deeper as you and I did. :-)

Comment: Great answer but when it comes to fault finding it's very tricky as a loose connection was giving a temporary reading for a second then going dead when connected to the motor but when it wasnt just completely dead!!!